# まし vs 楽 when used as comparison

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference in using 楽 and まし. For example:
死んだほうがましだ against 死んだほうが楽だ. They both mean "It is easier to die (than to do something else)"

Comment: Have you tried looking these terms up in a [dictionary](https://jisho.org/)? They mean fairly different things.

Comment: @Mindful yea I did, but while they mean "easier" and "better" when used individually, in the sentence such as the above, they sound the same to me

Comment: 楽 doesn't mean easy in this context. Check the dictionary again. @Newbie

Comment: @Fireheart251 Does it mean relief? But why can't it mean easy? There really isn't much context to begin with, so how would one know which it means? Especially since the 2 meanings are polar opposites

Comment: Easy may be appropriate here for the colloquial usage meaning "easier on me", I.E. more comfortable. However, I don't understand how "It would be easier/more comfortable if I died" and "It would be better if I died" can sound the same; at the very least that's not a Japanese language issue.

Answer (score 2):

They are semantically different words. 楽 means *easy* (antonym for *tough/tiresome/hard*) whereas まし is nuanced *better*, or "not satisfactory but at least better than something even worse" (See: [What's the meaning and usage of ~マシだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40221/5010)).

死んだほうが楽だ and 死んだほうがましだ does not sound that different simply because 死ぬ is a thing that is normally both *tough* and *bad*. But *tough* and *bad* is not always the same. For example, imagine you are a traveler and decided to take a long, steep but safe mountain road, avoiding a short but bandit-appearing road. In this case, the mountain path is *tougher* but *better*. So you would say こちらの山道の方がマシだ, but not こちらの山道の方が楽だ.